# Is there a way to search for a string in only those files where a previous search found a different string?

Tags: visual-studio-code, development-environment

I can't manage to find a way to make special edition, e.g., changing a string 'ABC' with a text 'TEXT1  TEXT2' in only files that already met a search criteria that I want.

Example: in all the files that contain the string '-FI-' replace the string 'ABC' with the string 'TEXT1  TEXT2'.

Is there a way/feature to do it please?, I have VScode 1.37.1 installed on Windows10. I want something that can be run in VScode and in worst case maybe some linux stuff can help ...

I tried for example how to make a search inside a search and edit. And I don't have enough knowledge to do it using regex.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "in all files that contain the string '-FI-'", do you mean that string appears in the file *name* or the file *contents*?

Comment: I mean in the file content.

Comment: In that case, VSCode by itself cannot do that.  Have you looked at the available [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)?  Also, are you only interested in solutions that work inside VSCode, or is it acceptable to use the command line, completely independent of VSCode?  And if so, is a [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)-based solution acceptable, or must it only use `cmd.exe` or Powershell?

Comment: I didn't see extensions, yes something with Cygwin can help ! , I already have it installed but I am not an expert with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clarifying comments, I interpret the question to be:

- How can I replace all instances of "ABC" with "TEXT1 TEXT2" within files that also contain the string "-Fl-", starting at a given directory and recursively considering all files beneath it?

I would solve this using Cygwin shell commands rather than in VSCode.

First, let's make a file that contains the names of all the files that contain the string "-Fl-".  At a `bash` shell, use `cd` to go to the directory of interest, and run:

```
  $ grep -l -r -- '-Fl-' . > files.txt
```

Breaking this down:

- [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) searches for text within files.
- The `-l` switch prints the file names rather than matching lines.
- The `-r` switch searches recursively in subdirectories.
- The `--` switch tells `grep` that that is the last command line *option*, so subsequent words should be treated as *arguments* (i.e., text to search for).  This is necessary because our search text begins with `-` and hence would otherwise be treated as an option.
- The `-Fl-` is the text to search for (case sensitive; use the `-i` option for case insensitive search).
- The `.` is the place for `grep` to search, and means "current directory" (plus all files and subdirectories, recursively, due to `-r`).
- The `> files.txt` part says to write the results to `files.txt`.

Before going on, open `files.txt` in an editor or just [`cat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) it to the terminal to verify that it looks reasonable to you:

```
  $ cat files.txt
```

Now we need to do search and replace in this list of files.  This isn't so easy to do with just stock shell commands, so I've written my own script that I use to do it:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smcpeak/scripts/master/replace-across-files

Save that as a file called "replace-across-files".  I normally put such things into `$HOME/scripts`, also known as `~/scripts`, so I will assume you've done the same (make that directory first if necessary).

Now, go back to the directory that has `files.txt` and run:

```
  perl ~/scripts/replace-across-files 'ABC' 'TEXT1 TEXT2' $(cat files.txt)
```

This will interactively prompt you for each occurrence.  Use `y` (or just Enter) to accept each one individually, `Y` to accept all in the current file, and `!` to make all replacements.

If you get `perl: command not found`, then you need to install Cygwin [perl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perl) first.

One possible gotcha: if any of the file names contain a space, then this won't work because `$(cat files.txt)` splits `files.txt` at whitespace boundaries before putting the contents onto the command line.  One way to deal with this is to use [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) instead:

```
  $ cat files.txt | xargs -d '\n' perl ~/scripts/replace-across-files -f 'ABC' 'TEXT1 TEXT2'
```

Breaking this down:

- `cat files.txt |` feeds the contents of `files.txt` to the next command, `xargs`, as its input.
- `xargs` adds its input onto the given command line and runs it.
- `-d '\n'` tells `xargs` to divide its input at *newline* boundaries, not any whitespace.
- `-f` tells `replace-across-files` to do all replacements non-interactively.  This is necessary because, due to the way `xargs` works, prompting for each replacement would not work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this what I need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple using an extension I wrote that can use the results from one search to limit the files searched in a second, third, etc. search.  Using the [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false) extension, make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+m",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {
    "find": ["-F1-", "ABC"],
    "replace": ["", "TEXT1 TEXT2"],
    "filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],
    "triggerReplaceAll": true,
    // "delay": 250              // a pause between searches, in milliseconds
  }
}
```

`"find": ["-F1-", "ABC"],` runs 2 finds, first for `-F1-` and then for `ABC`.

`"replace": ["", "TEXT1 TEXT2"],` two replaces, but the first does nothing (it does NOT replace `-F1-` with an empty string).

`"filesToInclude": ["", "${resultsFiles}"],` the  first `""` clears the files to include input, and the second will populate the files to include search input with only the files that were found with the previous search.

- If you wanted to start the first search in a particular directory, you could put something into that first `""`, like `${relativeFileDirname}` for example or a few other variables or any string value representing a folder or file path.

`"delay": 250` for searching larger groups of files, there must be a delay between each search if you are doing multiple searches like in the current case.  This is to allow vscode to complete the previous search and populate the search results.  There is a default delay of `2000` or 2 seconds but you can try shorter or longer `delay` values for your situation.

[image: multiple searches with the results of previous searches]